# Adding object to list

Tags: java

I have a `Building` class with a `rooms` property of type `List`:

```
private List<Room> rooms;
```

I wrote the following method to add an room to the list:

```
public void addRoom(Room room) {
        this.rooms.add(room);
    }
```

This code is not raising an exception immediately, but the room is not added to list. Also, the method is called in an iteration, after returning from `addRoom` method to this iteration, the next iterations are skipped and then an `NullPointerException` is raised.

I'm creating Room objects from a file. Here's how I call the method:

```
Room newRoom = new Room();
newRoom.setName(meetingRoom[0]);
newRoom.setCode(meetingRoom[1]);
few more setters ...
home.addRoom(newRoom);
```

home is an instance of Building found by another method earlier, its value is ok according to the debugger.

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: Have you ever initialized `rooms` to a new `ArrayList<>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your List ever instantiated?

Try with

```
private List<Room> rooms = new LinkedList<>();
```